# A special binomial identity in need of a proof

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, combinatorial-identities

I've encountered a curious identity as a codicil in some work. Is there a proof or reference?

$$\sum_{k=-n}^n\frac{2k+1}{n+k+1}\binom{2n}{n-k}\frac{x^k}{1+x^{2k+1}}=\frac{x^n}{1+x^{2n+1}}.$$

Comment: The right-hand denominator can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The $k=j-1$ and $k=-j$ terms cancel, so all that's left is the $k=n$ term.